# LINQ INNER SELECT WITH TOP

Tags: c#, linq

I want my end result to be a Generic List of type Country (without changing any shapes). What linq query would i write to give me top 3 States where StateName begins with 'S' within all Countries where CountryName begins with 'C'

IE: I want to search on my inner object as well as outer object, but restrict the count of my inner object to X

```
public class Country
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public List <State> StateList { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Any() to check if any of the states for a given country start with 'S'. Take() lets you limit the number of results.

With the following query you limit the number of states to (max) three:

```
List<Country> result = (from c in countries
                                where c.CountryName.StartsWith("C") && c.StateList.Any(s => s.StateName.StartsWith("S"))
                                select new Country()
                                           {

                                               CountryName = c.CountryName,
                                               StateList = (from s in c.StateList
                                                            where s.StateName.StartsWith("S")
                                                            select s).Take(3).ToList()
                                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: is a select new necessary? basically in real scenario, i am going to be doing this on 18.5 million inner records so just worried about performance

Comment: Are you using Linq to Entities with the Entity Framework? If so, you can use the Change Tracking mechanism with automatic fixup for this scenario. But to be honest, on 18,5 million records every option you use will take some time.